# Android: Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so

Tags: android

I have an Android game running on production in the google play store. Recently I received a complaint about the game not opening. The following crash appeared on my Crash Report. I suspect it has something to do with the images I'm displaying when the activity starts, but I have no idea what exactly is causing this. I would really appreciate some guidance as to how to approach this issue.

Thanks!

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Asus/omni_tf300t/tf300t:4.4.4/KTU84P/293:...'
Revision: '0'
pid: 7165, tid: 7165, name: ... >>> ... <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 00001bfd r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 0000000c r6 00001bfd r7 0000010c
r8 57921d90 r9 58ab366b sl 00000001 fp bee5e0a8
ip 41548bac sp bee5dd78 lr 401400ad pc 4014f098 cpsr 000f0010
d0 74726f6261204d56 d1 7320666f20656c62
d2 2e736f2e6c616e72 d3 6e4965746f67795a
d4 6957656e6f68502e d5 63654424776f646e
d6 6f2e77656956726f d7 46776f646e69576e
d8 3f8000003f800000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000005
d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000001
d20 0000000000004000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000004000 d23 0000000000000001
d24 0000000000000000 d25 000001e9000001e7
d26 0794c000078ec000 d27 07a0c000079ac000
d28 077cc1e00776c1de d29 0788c1e30782c1e1
d30 0794c1e6078ec1e4 d31 07a0c1e9079ac1e7
scr 68000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00022098 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 000130a9 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 000132bd /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00011ff3 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 0002194c /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00045beb /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
#06 pc 00027eb0 /system/lib/libdvm.so (IndirectRefTable::get(void*) const+216)
#07 pc 0004a487 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+30)
#08 pc 000603f7 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+158)
#09 pc 0004c8ed /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 0007831b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#11 pc 000790c1 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+104)
#12 pc 0007915b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaPixelAllocator::allocPixelRef(SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+18)
#13 pc 0009bfd5 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::allocPixels(SkBitmap::Allocator*, SkColorTable*)+28)
#14 pc 001003b5 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPNGImageDecoder::onDecode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+220)
#15 pc 000fc5b5 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkImageDecoder::decode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkBitmap::Config, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+36)
#16 pc 00076309 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#17 pc 00076479 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#18 pc 0001dbcc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#19 pc 0004e043 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#20 pc 00026fe0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#21 pc 0002df9c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#22 pc 0002b640 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#23 pc 0006078d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#24 pc 000686fb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#25 pc 00026fe0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#26 pc 0002df9c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#27 pc 0002b640 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#28 pc 000604ab /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
#29 pc 00049c2b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#30 pc 0004de7b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#31 pc 0004eb9f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
```

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this issue?